# finding a position of an element in a list of lists in functional programming

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I  am looking for an elegant solution for finding the position of an element in a seq of sequences. e.g.

```
def findChar(c: Char, levelVector: Vector[Vector[Char]]): (x,y) = {
     val x = levelVector.indexWhere(vect=>vect.indexOf(c) != -1)
    (x,levelVector(x).indexOf(c))
}
```

this works fine, but somehow I have a gut feeling, there should be a better elegant solution , some scala or FP construct which i am not able to recall [long years of imperative programming can do this kind of damage :) ].
which lets me do the work of

```
vect.indexOf(c)
```

only once. I have explored other constructs like flattening or for comprehension, but does not seems elegant or simple.
we can assume that vector is non-empty and element is unique.

any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
def findChar(c: Char, levelVector: Vector[Vector[Char]]) = {
  // view is to ensure indices are only calculated up to the element you need
  val vec1 = levelVector.view.map(_.indexOf(c))
  val x = vec1.indexWhere(_ != -1)
  if (x != -1)
    Some((x, vec1(x)))
  else
    None // or (-1, -1) if you prefer
}
```

Comment: did not know that view is a lazy collection. Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Neither elegant nor succinct, but a solution nevertheless, one that I hammered out because I forced myself to do it using a for comprehension:

```
  def findChar(c: Char, levelVector: Vector[Vector[Char]]): (Int, Int) = {
    val y = for (
      i <- 0 to levelVector.view.length - 1;
      v = levelVector.view(i);

      j = v.indexOf(c) if j != -1
    ) yield (i, j)

    y.take(1)(0)
  }
```

I might delete this answer soon :-)